# What do emotes actually do?

Tags: the-division

Apart from being funny, do emotes in the division actually have any purpose in game? TF2 for example has taunts which actually do damage, but emotes don't seem to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emotes are purely aesthetic, but have social benefits. They allow basic communication, if you do not have access to a microphone.

A good example of this is in the dark zone. If you fire on a regular player, you go rogue. If you are defeated as a rogue, you have more to lose, and if a player kills you, they have more to gain. It is not uncommon to accidentally hit another player with a few stray bullets, marking yoursef as rogue, and giving them the impression that you are trying to kill them. Normally, you would simply say sorry, over microphone. Most of the time, the other player says 'don't worry about it', and leaves you to your own devices. In this situation, emotes would allow a player to quickly communicate, without having a microphone. The player could wave to the other player, or more deliberately, perform the 'surrender' emote.

Comment: Great explanation, I couldn't find this info anywhere. I am guessing though that while doing an emote you are still vulnerable to gunfire? In that case wouldn't performing one be putting yourself in danger of eating a bullet?

Comment: @FrontEnd, definetly. But if you fire on a player with higher gear score by accident, and and they think you intend to continue, you'll probably be eating a bullet, anyway. The dark zone doesnt populate itself with enough players to be a real issue, and enemy NPCs probably won't be doing much in a single shot, assuming your appropriately geared.